# RTMP stream using JWPlayer

Tags: video-streaming, jwplayer, rtmp, live-streaming, jwplayer7

I tried searching the previous questions but they didn't help. They might be to old.
I created an RTMP server on Digital Ocean using Nginx and the RTMP plugin. I then downloaded and connected OBS to my RTMP server. It's working because programs like VLC and MPlayer can play the stream. However, JWPlayer doesn't seem to want to. I am posting this on a Wordpress page.
I already tried going over https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1430358-using-rtmp-streaming but it didn't help me much, maybe it can you guys.  I'm using the latest JWPlayer 7.6.1

Here is my code:

```
<div id="myElement"></div>
<script>
var playerInstance = jwplayer("myElement");
playerInstance.setup({
file: "rtmp://meeting.lwhf.com/live",
image: "http://example.com/jwplayer-7.6.1/out-of-their-heart.jpg",
width: 768,
primary: "flash",
height: 432,
});
</script>
```

The error I am receiving is: Failed to setup Flash. Error: An Invalid exception was thrown.
Thank you!

Comment: I'm unable to play that rtmp stream on Vlc.

Comment: Sounds like a Flash error. What browser/device are you using?